# Would a Polycom video camera be suitable for astrophotography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, astrophotography

Have Polycom FX video conference camera 1024 x780. Could this be used for astro photography? Just curious for a project. Appreciate input.

Comment: For what it's worth, my first concern would be the resolution.  When you consider that your subjects are basically tiny little specks, a low resolution format would be suboptimal and would greatly limit what you could do with it, especially if it has a wider focal length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the camera for high resolution astrophotography of the planets for example, if you also have a telescope and you're willing to take the camera apart. 
Some (paid) tutorials can be found here http://www.damianpeach.com/dvd.htm, but you can easily find more info online about the topic. The learning curve is very steep and I'd recommend that you use a specialized camera for this topic as well, some of the cheapest are roughly 100$.

For other types of astrophotography such as landscape astrophotography it's a waste of time to try and use the video conference camera.